# Show that there is no modulus with an odd prime number of primitive roots

Tags: modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Show that there is no modulus with an odd prime number of primitive roots. I'm not really sure how to approach this at all. I was thinking of using the property that there exists a primitive root modulo $m$ if and only if $m = 2, 4$ or $m$ is of the form $p^k$ or $2p^k$, but I'm not really sure what to do next.

Comment: If $a$ is a primitive root is $-a$ ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  did you mean $a^{-1}$?

Comment: No but that's also a good consideration @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  But $5$ is a primitive root $\pmod 7$ while $2$ isn't, for example.  Or, more simply, $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod 3$ while $1$ is not.

Comment: Yes and what I was pointing out was that if $-1$ as a residue shows up in one line, $1$ is the residue of the line of it's additive inverse at that same exponent.  For multiplicative inverses they end up at multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are any primitive roots modulo $m$ at all, then there are $\varphi(\varphi(m))$ of them. Being a totient, it could never be an odd number greater than $1$, regardless of primality.